# Why is my Switch not charging?

Tags: nintendo-switch

So I started charging my Switch, expecting a small lightning icon on the corner of the screen, but nothing appeared. I tried seeing if the console had any battery left, or if it was on. Nothing. Someone please help. Is it broken? Is the battery drained?

[image: This is my Nintendo Switch charging right now]

Comment: What are you trying to illustrate with the picture? That it's plugged in?

Comment: How long has it been plugged in? Was it turned on before you started charging it? If the battery was completely drained, it might be that it has to first charge enough that it has enough power to turn on. Maybe try leaving it charging for a while, see if anything changes.

Comment: Does it charge properly through the official dock?  Have you tried other outlets?  (Maybe that outlet isn't providing power for some reason)?  In general, please let us know what you've already tried so we can tailor our answers to your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure if we have enough information to suggest any particular solution here. You might want to check out the Nintendo Support website. If their troubleshooting FAQ's don't help, you can reach out to their support team. Here's the link: http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/landing/p/897

Comment: What if the charger dosen't provide enough power, the lowest it will charge at is 5v.

Answer (score 2):

Was your Switch out of charge? If it completely runs out, then you'll have to charge it for a bit before you can turn it on. When you charge it while it's completely out of charge, you will get no visual cue indicating that it is charging, until it has enough to turn on. Try leaving it charging for a few minutes, then check if it has enough charge to turn on.

If you still can't figure out why it doesn't seem to be charging, try taking it back to the game shop to see if they can figure it out.